# can't installl plugin add phonegap-plugin-push ionic 3

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

when i install plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
then i run ionic cordova build ios i got an error 
[image]

and then i remove platform ios then add this again i got an error
[image]

everything ok when i do on android

Answer (score 1):

Can you give more info about your source. Run 'ionic info'.
And, here are the command I always use after install new plugin for Cordova to build iOS, try with it:

```
npm run ionic state restore --plugins
```

Goodluck!

Comment: Did you install CocoaPods for iOS platform?
https://imgur.com/5jG2OcJ

See this doc to make sure all requirement are passed. Hope to work with you!
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md